# #error "Must #define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS before #including Support/DataTypes.h"

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, llvm, bison, flex-lexer

I have been trying to follow the tutorial at http://gnuu.org/2009/09/18/writing-your-own-toy-compiler/5/ (using flex, bison and llvm) but when typing the line

> g++ -o parser parser.cpp tokens.cpp main.cpp

I get the following errors:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/llvm/Support/PointerLikeTypeTraits.h:18:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/llvm/ADT/PointerIntPair.h:17,
                 from /usr/local/include/llvm/IR/Use.h:28,
                 from /usr/local/include/llvm/IR/Value.h:17,
                 from node.h:3,
                 from parser.y:2:
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/DataTypes.h:48:3: erreur: #error "Must #define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS before #including Support/DataTypes.h"
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/DataTypes.h:52:3: erreur: #error "Must #define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS before " "#including Support/DataTypes.h"
parser.y: In function ‘void yyerror(const char*)’:
parser.y:6:58: erreur: ‘printf’ was not declared in this scope
In file included from /usr/local/include/llvm/Support/PointerLikeTypeTraits.h:18:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/llvm/ADT/PointerIntPair.h:17,
                 from /usr/local/include/llvm/IR/Use.h:28,
                 from /usr/local/include/llvm/IR/Value.h:17,
                 from node.h:3,
                 from tokens.l:3:
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/DataTypes.h:48:3: erreur: #error "Must #define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS before #including Support/DataTypes.h"
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/DataTypes.h:52:3: erreur: #error "Must #define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS before " "#including Support/DataTypes.h"
In file included from /usr/local/include/llvm/Support/PointerLikeTypeTraits.h:18:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/llvm/ADT/PointerIntPair.h:17,
                 from /usr/local/include/llvm/IR/Use.h:28,
                 from /usr/local/include/llvm/IR/Value.h:17,
                 from node.h:3,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/DataTypes.h:48:3: erreur: #error "Must #define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS before #including Support/DataTypes.h"
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/DataTypes.h:52:3: erreur: #error "Must #define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS before " "#including Support/DataTypes.h"
```

I have seen lots of posts like this on the internet, and most of the answers include defining these constants on the command line or by using gcc Makefile.

I don't understand how to do that, could someone help me out?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Append this to your command line:

```
-D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
```

For more information about the `-D` command line option, refer to [gcc's documentation on preprocessor options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html).

Comment: @Oak Unfortunately I still get the errors after adding this command line option. Any clues? I'm on OSX.

Comment: @gideon sorry, no. You better ask on [LLVM-dev](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/mailman/listinfo/llvmdev).

Answer (score 8):

Based on the docs [here](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/System_2DataTypes_8h_source.html), you should be able to fix the problem by adding the following command line options:

```
-D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
```

Afterwards, there might be some other errors:

> parser.o: In function `NInteger::NInteger(long long)':
>   parser.cpp:(.text._ZN8NIntegerC2Ex[_ZN8NIntegerC5Ex]+0x23): undefined reference to`vtable for NInteger'
>   parser.o: In function `NDouble::NDouble(double)':
>   parser.cpp:(.text._ZN7NDoubleC2Ed[_ZN7NDoubleC5Ed]+0x24): undefined reference to`vtable for NDouble'

Try to implement every **codeGen** in every class without `llvm` stuff (i.e., change `node.h`). Then you will be able to compile and run the tutorial.

By the way, when you compile the code, you might want to use `llvm-config` command the get the option instead of using `-D` option:

```
g++ -c `llvm-config --cppflags`  xxxx.cpp
```